# Javascript: String comparison returns true although the strings are different (intermittent issue)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm processing the data in chunks using `WritableStream`. The decoded data is a json string and in case it starts with `,` I need to remove the comma.

But here's the problem, after the chunk is being decoded to string I'm checking the first character

```js
const startsWithComma = chunk.at(0) === ','
```

and **SOMETIMES** it returns true although the chunk doesn't start with `,` and causes the `JSON.parse` to fail later on. See the attached image.

Things I tried:

- used `.at()` alternatives like `.charAt()`, `.startsWith()`, `chunk[0]`

The issue is intermittent meaning sometimes it can process the entire data and sometimes might fail mid through.

[image: code example]

Comment: from your image, is it possible that the debug is running after the comma was already taken out? is it also possible that the chunk may begin with more than 1 comma so sometimes debugging at that exact spot would still show a comma?

Comment: have you tried to do it with `==` instead of `===`

Comment: @TheBombSquad yes, you're right that's exactly what is happening. The `chunk` does have a comma in its initial state but the debugger shows the final state with no comma. Feel free to answer the question and I'll approve. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, expanding on my comment:

> from your image, is it possible that the debug is running after the comma was already taken out? is it also possible that the chunk may begin with more than 1 comma so sometimes debugging at that exact spot would still show a comma?

The solution would be to take off the commas using a while loop such as

```js
while( chunk.at(0)===',' ){
  chunk = chunk.slice(1).trim();
}
```

now I do not know the reason for doing it if `isFirstChunk` so I'd leave that alone, but the above loop should solve your `startsWithComma` issue :D